# put php query in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've a little problem, I've a query and i'would like that the result will go in an array.

```
function disponibilita($data) {
    $this->sql_open();
    $db=$this->db;

    $sql="SELECT id FROM turni WHERE date='$data'";$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($id);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        printf ("%s", $id);
    }
}   `
```

printf stamp the right results, how to put into array the results of this dbquery?

Comment: See **[MySQLi Fetch All](http://www.php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php)**

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) for PDO
, or check out [mysqli_result::fetch_all](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) for mysqli

```
function disponibilita($data) {
    $this->sql_open();
    $db=$this->db;
    $sql="SELECT id FROM turni WHERE date='$data'";
    $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // for PDO
    $results = $stmt->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // for mysqli

    return $results;
}
```

Comment: @BenFortune actually it looks like he does!

Comment: @Dwza `bind_result()` is a MySQLi method.

Comment: @BenFortune didn't see `bind_result`. Use case for both `PDO` and `mysqli` added.